# iOS 7 Autolayout

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

Can someone please guide me in the right direction? I am not asking someone to do it for me, I am just asking for help. I am relatively new to iOS development.

My app is a universal app and it needs to support the 3.5" screen, 4" screen and the iPad. The following UI is designed for the 4" screen but I need to get the UIButtons, UILabels, and UITextFields to resize and realign according to the screen size. Everything is embedded inside of a UIScrollView. Can someone explain what kind of constraints I need? I have tried many different things but I just cannot get it to work properly. I have tried using springs and struts but I can't get the UITextFields to align with everything else on the iPad.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Storyboard 4"]

This is how it should display with the 3.5" screen
[image: Storyboard 3.5"]

This is what it shows in the simulator
[image: Simulator 3.5"]

Comment: If you need general information on auto layout you should watch the WWDC videos / read the documentation on the subject. For this question to be succinctly answerable more detail is required; for example... "realign according to screen size", in what way? What behavior are you trying to accomplish. "cannot get it to work properly", how so? What is it doing/not doing that is not as you expected/desired? Also, even with that information, we would need to see the specific constraints applied to the view you posted. Consider posting an image of the inspector showing the view/constraint nodes.

Comment: @NJones I have read the documentation but I still wasn't able to understand. I should probably watch the WWDC demo. I have edited my post to show what it should look like with the 3.5" screen. Oddly, if I run the simulator with the 3.5" view in the storyboard, it displays what it displays in the storyboard. If I run the simulator with the 4" view it displays incorrectly as shown in the screenshot. I'm going to have test with a 3.5" phone.

Comment: I presume all of those prices are individual labels. Surely a better, more scalable approach would be to place them in an UITableView with static cells.

Comment: @Programming Thomas those are actually buttons. It's a counting app so those are used for incrementing/decrementing.

Comment: watch about autolayots as said @NJones wwdc, or read up https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 3):

I am an experienced ios and OSX developer, and it took me a while to get this technology working. A big mistake many make including me is to start with a big project. It's often more productive to take baby steps in a small one and play with the technology.

Read then reread the autolayout guide. It has all you need in a compact form. I bought Erica Sadun's book on autolayout - you will find it a great help (also Matt Neuburgs ios7 book has a nice chapter on this).

So, to your immediate need. For complex views I've personally found in the end it's easier to do the work in code. If you've used vertical distance constraints, then you need to get references to each as outlets, or you need to iterate throughout the array and find them all in viewDidLoad. Once you have them you can change their constant value to adjust the spacing to best adapt to the current phone height.

Another way to do this is with "spacer" views (more constraints, thus better in code). In this method every text field has a clear empty view between it and the one below it. Each of these spacers touches two text fields, and each but the top most is constrained to be the same vertical height as the top one. The constraint system the finds the exact size of the first to make everything fit.

You can actually do this as a hybrid solution - remove the handful of vertical constraints in your storyboard view, leave the working horizontal ones, and add the missing vertical ones in code. But try that in a simple dem project first.

Comment: I keep reading the same thing about Auto Layout all over the internet. It's a tough concept to grasp but I think it should payoff to learn it. I think I should try as many different tutorials I can on my own. I've done a couple but it wasn't enough. Thanks.

Comment: I just did an app for use internally at my company - it supports 3.5 and 4" iPhone, both landscape and portrait. All with constraints. Once you get the flow and have some working views, its easy to get it for subsequent ones. No more pages of setFrame:, setFrame, setFrame! Sadun recommends developing your own set of libraries, has many good hints - worth the $$$ for the book IMHO.

Comment: I will definitely check that out. I've learned most of my iOS development from Stanford's Coding Together course but there is still a lot to learn. I'm a full time computer science student right now and the only thing preventing me from getting good at iOS development is time. Every time I start learning, a new version of iOS comes along. Especially with iOS 7, it's difficult to support older versions of iOS without having a different design for them.